# Why does not gcc and clang warn for unused result of library functions?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, compiler-warnings

Consider this code:

```
int __attribute__((warn_unused_result)) foo(void)
{
    return 42;
}

int main(void)
{
    foo();
}
```

When compiled, it emits a warning:

```
$ gcc main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:8:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘foo’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
    8 |     foo();
      |     ^~~~~
```

This is as expected. What I wonder is if there is any rationale why some many standard library functions is not declared with this attribute. I'm talking about functions like `scanf` where checking the return value is crucial in most cases, and also functions like `malloc` which is completely pointless if you do not use the return value. However, `realloc` seems to have this.

Is there any reason for not declaring scanf, malloc etc functions with `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`? I think this could have prevented many bugs.

Comment: But [scanf](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/include/stdio.h#L86) has that attribute. [Some](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/string/string.h#L429) other functions also. You have to define [_FORTIFY_SOURCE](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/misc/sys/cdefs.h#L304)

Comment: Maybe someone decided that stdio.h is a hopeless case anyway. Most of it is plain dangerous and it ought to be the worst programming library all categories in the history of programming, that has caused the most bugs and material damage to mankind. Compared to the unsalvageable mess of format strings, variadic functions, horrible APIs, some 35 different cases of explicit undefined behavior... well, forgetting to check the result of scanf is just one drop in the stdio.h bug ocean. The library provides numerous other ways to screw up code with buffer overflows and out of bounds access.

Comment: @KamilCuk That's weird. I don't get any warnings.

Comment: @klutt Aaand you have to enable optimizations [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/3ze587)

Comment: @KamilCuk Tested both clang and gcc with O3. No warning.

Answer (score 3):

It may be enlightening to think about why *these specific* functions get `warn_unused_result`—this may help us figure out why other functions don’t get the attribute. On my Glibc system, there are only two such functions:

```
extern void *realloc (void *__ptr, size_t __size)
     __THROW __attribute_warn_unused_result__ __attribute_alloc_size__ ((2));
extern void *reallocarray (void *__ptr, size_t __nmemb, size_t __size)
     __THROW __attribute_warn_unused_result__
     __attribute_alloc_size__ ((2, 3));
```

On my macOS system, there are three:

```
void    *malloc(size_t __size) __result_use_check __alloc_size(1);
void    *calloc(size_t __count, size_t __size) __result_use_check __alloc_size(1,2);
void    *realloc(void *__ptr, size_t __size) __result_use_check __alloc_size(2);
```

So, why does this super-useful attribute only get used on `realloc()` and another near-identical function in Glibc?

The answer is because this attribute is designed to prevent a very specific bug. Let's say we have a 100-element array and want to resize it to add a 101st element (at index 100) (and let's ignore error handling):

```
// Create 100-element array.
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
arr[99] = 1234;
// Resize and add a 101st element.
realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * 101); // bug
arr[100] = 1234;
```

Spot the bug? This is a **serious memory error** but it is also a memory error that may or may not get noticed very quickly. The original `malloc` will often round up to a larger size in the first place, and if `realloc` succeeds, you may end up with the same address anyway. The actual bug will only get noticed once you start writing into another object, or once another object gets allocated at the old address for `arr`.

This is something that might take you a while to debug.

So, the warning is designed to catch this *serious* bug that is difficult to debug. Compare with the following:

```
malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
```

This bug isn’t very serious at all—it’s just a memory leak. It’s not even incorrect code!

As a fun exercise, try putting the above code into Godbolt and looking at the assembly output—GCC will actually *remove* the call to `malloc` entirely.

As for `printf`, `scanf`, and others—

```
int r = printf(...);
if (r == -1) {
    abort();
}
```

If GCC gave warnings for not checking the return of `printf`, people would get frustrated because they would see too many warnings in their code—and they would respond by turning the warnings off.

So sometimes it is better to only trigger warnings for the most serious cases, and let some other cases slide.

---

As a minor technical note, this is somewhat more an issue for the standard library maintainers, like the Glibc team, rather than GCC or Clang. Even though the standard library and compiler are tightly integrated, they are separate projects—and you can even swap out different standard libraries. For example, you might use musl, glibc, or Apple’s libSystem.

Comment: `only get used` but it doesn't! [godbolt link with scanf unused return warning](https://godbolt.org/z/3ze587) you have to `-O -D_FORTIFY_LEVEL=1`. For other functions it's an optional feature, so that programmers can choose the behavior.

Comment: When it comes to printf, I completely understand it, but not scanf.

Comment: Completely useless `if(realloc(arr, sizeof(*arr) * 101)) arr[100] = 10;` return value used same error

Comment: BTW `sizeof(int)` => `sizeof(*arr)` is safer

Comment: @P__J__ I can’t understand what you wrote. `sizeof(int)` here is used here for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not portable.
2. Standard does not **require** it.
3. You can always write the wrapper if you want be warned.

```
static inline void * __attribute__((warn_unused_result, always_inline)) mymalloc(size_t size)
{
    return malloc(size);
}

int main(void)
{
    mymalloc(300);
}
```

Comment: I cannot see how portability plays a part here.

Comment: Also, does the standard require realloc to issue this warning?

Comment: attribute is not very portable I believe

Comment: @klutt standard does not require return value to be used, thus no warnings.

Comment: Yep, but the portability does not matter. If I'm going to compile a program with another compiler I'm not gonna copy the standard library. Adding that attribute would not cause any portability issues as far as I can see.

Comment: And regarding realloc, obviously the creators behind gcc and clang decided that realloc should issue this warning but not scanf.